# Matlab 3D surface normal distribution

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d, surface

I have two normal distributions and i am trying to make a volumetric surface from them. I got the following graph

[image]

```
clear; clc;

nsamp = 100000;

%

% Basic variables

%

m1=2.724;

dp1=0.375;

R = normrnd(m1,dp1, nsamp, 1);

m2=1.345;

dp2=0.135;

S = normrnd(m2,dp2, nsamp, 1);

%

Z = R - S;


    I = (Z < 0);

pf = sum(I)/nsamp

beta = -norminv(pf)

%

% Histograms

hist(S,20)

hold on

hist(R,40)

set(findobj('Type','patch'),'Facecolor','none','Edgecolor','black')

set(gca,'Fontsize',18,'Fontname','euclid')

xlabel('R & S')


figure

scatterhist(R,S)

xlabel('R'),ylabel('S')
```

and i would like to make a 3D surface and the points in red to remain in red and the blue points in blue. Can someone help me? Regards

Comment: "volume" implies three dimensions. What would you like the third dimension to represent?

Comment: <http://jitkomut.lecturer.eng.chula.ac.th/matlab/_images/gaussian8.png The frequency of the result function density.

Comment: That is the pretended surface. But the colors are not. I would like to be blue and red only. Thanks mate!

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging for details - but how do you want the colors to show up. Do you want two surfaces - one all blue, and one all red? Or do you want a single Gaussian that is more blue when it's blue, and more red when it's red? It's hard to read your mind on this...

Comment: If you run that code you can see two types of points: red and blue. I would like a single Gaussian surface that is blue and red at the same time, according to the I vector. I dont know if i explained myself in the proper way... Sorry mate and thanks a lot for your dedication and time! :)

Comment: I know what the plot looks like as a scatter gram. I have no idea what you want the surface to look like. "blue and red at the same time" - how is that supposed to work? Is the surface the sum of the density of the two? Is the color a mixture of red and blue based on the relative prevalence at a given position?

Comment: The I vector saves the results that will decide if the points are blue or red. The z axis will be the frequency of those points. When I is lower than zero, the points are red. When I is equal or bigger than zero, the points are blue. Do you think it is possible? Sorry man, to bother so much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a tested solution right now - not access to Matlab license server. But you have two problems here.

The first is to create a surface plot of density. You can use the `hist3` function for the this - and if you return the values of the bins you can control the plotting yourself:

[N C] = histc(X)

(I'm sorry it is not clear to me what you really want to plot - is it `R`, `S`, `Z`, or `R+S`? that's why I used `X`).

Then to color the graph, you can use patch coloring - see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/specifying-patch-coloring.html for how to do that.

The combination of these two should get you a long way there... but it's still a little unclear what you really want to do. I hope these hints help you on your way.